# different pid cgi program

Tags: c, linux, apache, cgi

I have written this test CGI program in C.

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    sem_t *mysem;

    mysem = sem_open("/MyClient", O_CREAT | O_EXCL, S_IRUSR | S_IWUSR, 10);
    if(mysem == SEM_FAILED)
    {
        // already running
        if(errno == EEXIST)
        {
            fprintf(stdout, "Content-type:text/plain\n\n");
            fprintf(stdout, "Already running");
            exit(1);
        }
        else
        {
            fprintf(stdout, "[error] - ", errno);
            exit(1);
        }
    }

    fprintf(stdout, "Content-type:text/plain\n\n");
    int i = 0;
    for(;i <10; i++)
    {
        sleep(1);
    }

    fprintf(stdout, "all done by PID - %d\n", getpid());

    sem_unlink("MyClient");
    sem_close(mysem);

    return 0;
}
```

I am using Apache for web server.
when I goto "localhost/cgi-bin/mycgi" in my browser (I open two tabs, simultaneously).

**The output should be like this (expected)**

(for Tab1)
"all done by PID - 8186"

and (for Tab2) "Already running"

**But I get this (actual)**

(for Tab1)
"all done by PID - 8186"

and (for Tab2) "all done by PID - 8187"

The above code works as expected if I execute the program (2 instances) in my terminal.

Comment: Shouldn't you compare the result of `sem_open` call with `SEM_FAILED` instead?

Comment: result is same even if I use
if(mysem == SEM_FAILED)

Comment: you are not checking the return values of `sem_unlink` and `sem_close`...

Comment: I have checked `sem_unlink` and `sem_close` return 0 (success).

Answer (score 0):

From Ubuntu's `man sem_overview`:

> A named semaphore is identified by a name of the form /somename; that 
>   is,  a  null-terminated  string of up to NAME_MAX-4 (i.e., 251)
>   characters consisting of an initial slash, followed by  one or  more 
>   characters,  none of which are slashes.

IOW, your semaphore name is not valid.

Another thing, from `man sem_open`:

> If O_CREAT is specified in oflag, then two additional arguments must
>   be supplied. ...

The function will get random crap as `mode` and `value`, with predictably unpredictable results.

Comment: sorry I forgot to change the PID's while copy-pasting :-|
The PID's are different. If I open two tabs simultaneously in a browser, the second tab should display "Already running".

Comment: Added another, very likely reason.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I found an answer to my question [here](http://httpd.markmail.org/search/?q=single%20instance%20cgi#query%3asingle%20instance%20cgi%20page:1%20mid:3d3qrc4pbevn3w7q%20state%3aresults).

A browser may open one single connection to the server, and use that same connection to send several requests. That is what is called "keep-alive" connections. On the server side, this results in this one connection being handed over to one single Apache "child", and this single child keeps the connection open and processes all requests on that connection, one after the other.

No matter how many windows or tabs you open in the same browser, it *may* still be using only that one connection, for all its windows or tabs. But two different browsers (or the same browser on two different workstations) will not share one connection.

If I try this in two different browsers (Firefox and Chrome) simultaneously, it works as expected.